# Finding the recurring pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-recognition

Let's say I have a number with a recurring pattern, i.e. there exists a string of digits that repeat themselves in order to make the number in question. For example, such a number might be `1234123412341234`, created by repeating the digits `1234`.
What I would like to do, is find the pattern that repeats itself to create the number. Therefore, given `1234123412341234`, I would like to compute `1234` (and maybe `4`, to indicate that `1234` is repeated 4 times to create `1234123412341234`)

I know that I could do this:

```
def findPattern(num):
    num = str(num)
    for i in range(len(num)):
        patt = num[:i]
        if (len(num)/len(patt))%1:
            continue
        if pat*(len(num)//len(patt)):
            return patt, len(num)//len(patt)
```

However, this seems a little too hacky. I figured I could use `itertools.cycle` to compare two cycles for equality, which doesn't really pan out:

```
In [25]: c1 = itertools.cycle(list(range(4)))

In [26]: c2 = itertools.cycle(list(range(4)))

In [27]: c1==c2
Out[27]: False
```

Is there a better way to compute this? (I'd be open to a regex, but I have no idea how to apply it there, which is why I didn't include it in my attempts)

**EDIT**:

1. I don't necessarily know that the number has a repeating pattern, so I have to return `None` if there isn't one.
2. Right now, I'm only concerned with detecting numbers/strings that are made up entirely of a repeating pattern. However, later on, I'll likely also be interested in finding patterns that start after a few characters:

> magic_function(78961234123412341234)

would return `1234` as the pattern, `4` as the number of times it is repeated, and `4` as the first index in the input where the pattern first presents itself

Comment: What about something like `771177117711`? That's very difficult.

Comment: @AlexThornton: That's a pattern of `7711`, 3 times, or a pattern of `1177`, twice (with leading and trailing noise)

Comment: The regular expression fails for that, annoyingly. I'll see if I can think of anything.

Comment: @AlexThornton http://regex101.com/r/hO3xY3/3 it does not fail

Comment: @vks Sorry, I didn't see your edit.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget you have match ,then you can again apply you just have to do `len(re.findall(match,x,re.M))`.Here match is the match you found and `x`` is the original string.

Comment: @vks: that makes sense. I like it

Answer (score 5):

```
(.+?)\1+
```

Try this. Grab the capture. See [**demo**](http://regex101.com/r/hO3xY3/1).

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(.+?)\1+')
test_str = u"1234123412341234"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Add anchors and flag `Multiline` if you want the regex to fail on `12341234123123`, which should return `None`.

```
^(.+?)\1+$
```

See [**demo**](http://regex101.com/r/hO3xY3/2).

Comment: This line `p = re.compile(ur'(.+?)\1+')` should be changed to `p = re.compile(r'(.+?)\1+')`?

Comment: @muammar r u on python3?

Answer (score 0):

One way to find a recurring pattern and number of times repeated is to use this pattern:

```
(.+?)(?=\1+$|$)
```

w/ `g` option.
It will return the repeated pattern and number of matches (times repeated)
Non-repeated patterns (fails) will return only "**1**" match
Repeated patterns will return **2 or more** matches (number of times repeated).
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/90)

Comment: Would you be able to post an example of your code finding non-matches, etc?