# How to Identify Repetitive Characters in a String Using Python?

Tags: python, string, substring, pattern-recognition, dna-sequence

I am new to python and I want to write a program that determines if a string consists of repetitive characters.  The list of strings that I want to test are:

- Str1 = "AAAA"
- Str2 = "AGAGAG"
- Str3 = "AAA"

The pseudo-code that I come up with:

```
WHEN len(str) % 2 with zero remainder:
- Divide the string into two sub-strings. 
- Then, compare the two sub-strings and check if they have the same characters, or not.
- if the two sub-strings are not the same, divide the string into three sub-strings and compare them to check if repetition occurs.
```

I am not sure if this is applicable way to solve the problem,  Any ideas how to approach this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just simply iterate through the string and compare the next character with the current one?

Comment: Some options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26703839/198633)

Comment: @metatoaster I am not sure if that will work for all the strings I have listed.  Especially for Str2="AGAGAG" because the pattern here is a bit complex.

Comment: If you divide the string into `len(str)` substrings, you will always find that there is one repetition... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if a string repeats itself in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481088/how-can-i-tell-if-a-string-repeats-itself-in-python)

Comment: What do you want as a result?

Comment: a print statement that outputs the repeated characters in the string @DanD.

Comment: Please provide what the expected outputs for each input are. You're still being quite vague as to what you are expecting. Your answers are varying widely as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Counter library to count the most common occurrences of the characters.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = 'abcaaada'
>>> c = Counter(s)
>>> c.most_common()
[('a', 5), ('c', 1), ('b', 1), ('d', 1)]
```

To get the single most repetitive (common) character:

```
>>> c.most_common(1)
[('a', 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a [RegX backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

Answer (score 0):

To find a pattern in Python, you are going to need to use "Regular Expressions". A regular expression is typically written as:

```
match = re.search(pat, str)
```

This is usually followed by an if-statement to determine if the search succeeded.

for example this is how you would find the pattern "AAAA" in a string:

```
import re

string = ' blah blahAAAA this is an example'
match = re.search(r 'AAAA', string)

if match:
    print 'found', match.group()
else :
    print 'did not find'
```

This returns

> found 'AAAA'

Do the same for your other two strings and it will work the same.
Regular expressions can do a lot more than just this so work around with them and see what else they can do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the whole string is a repeating pattern, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29489919/1610388) has a good solution:

```
def principal_period(s):
    i = (s+s).find(s, 1, -1)
    return None if i == -1 else s[:i]
```